# Even though a program "runs as administrator", UAC still pops up

Tags: uac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does UAC still prompt me when “Run as Administrator” is permanently set?](https://superuser.com/questions/350632/why-does-uac-still-prompt-me-when-run-as-administrator-is-permanently-set)

I set up a program (KM Player in this case) to always run as Administrator (checkbox from the Compatibility Tab of its shortcut). Well, even like this, I still get an UAC prompt: "do you want to allow  program from an unknown publisher to make changes to this computer."

No matter what I do, this doesn't work. The UAC still prompts me even if I change the setting for all users.

I thought that if I check that checkbox, I won't be asked by the UAC every time I start the program. What's even worse is that even if I open files associated with that program (movies in this case), I still get the UAC prompt.

Is there no way to exclude that program from the UAC?

Comment: Thanks. Didn't turn up on my Google Search ::- ).

Comment: Actually, there is a solution, and the solution is right here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprogeneral/thread/1637c7b8-86b7-4d79-8982-d425c8ef4c67

Comment: Wow!  That's a nasty hack of a solution, but that's a nice find.

Comment: You have to ask yourself: "What happens if the user is not an administrator?"